# How to get the last rows per group in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a query that retrieves the reservation made by a team
the query computes and retrieves good but the problem is that I only want to retrieve the latest reservation made by the team but my query shows their first reservation made.

Here is the complete query

```
select 
    tbl_lab_reservations.id, 
    tbl_lab_reservations.full_desc, 
    serial_number, 
    rsvn_owner, 
    reservation_id, 
    reservation_date_end, 
    reservation_date_start,
    (SELECT DATEDIFF( if(reservation_date_end = '0000-00-00', CURDATE(), reservation_date_end), 
    reservation_date_start)+1) as totalNumberOfDaysReserve 
from tbl_lab_reservations 
join tbl_lab_assets on tbl_lab_assets.id = tbl_lab_reservations.lab_id 
where tbl_lab_reservations.full_desc = 'Dell Optiplex 380' 
and tbl_lab_reservations.asset_status = 'Idle' 
group by serial_number, rsvn_owner 
ORDER BY tbl_lab_reservations.id ASC
```

Comment: Please provide the DDL of tables and with some sample data and expected output from the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The query that you have given is correct for showing the records from first to latest as the order by clause is asc. To retrieve the latest record,

> change the order by clause to desc

from which you will get the latest record as the first one in the result(only if you have the **tbl_lab_reservations.id is unique for all records**).

To get only the latest record and omit the other, you have the limit keyword. The limit should be used at the end of the query to set the limit of records to be fetched.

**Syntax :** limit N ,where N specifies the number of record.

**Example for you.**

[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e832/12)

```
select id, events from msql
             where id < '05'
             group by id
             order by id desc
             limit 1
```